# gcc compile error invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct LadoSt’

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, sizeof

Im making a project for my university and compiling my files with a MakeFile im having trouble, i have 5 files: api.c api.h datastruct.c datastruct.h main.c
In main i have this function call: DovahkiinP new = NuevoDovahkiin();
the NuevoDovahkiin() function is defined in api.c and also the struct DovahkiinSt pointed by DovahkiinP

the function NuevoDovahkiin() is defined in api.c like this:

```
DovahkiinP NuevoDovahkiin(){
    DovahkiinP new_dovahkiin = NULL;
    new_dovahkiin = calloc(1, sizeof(struct DovahkiinSt)); //Here is the problem
    if(new_dovahkiin != NULL){
        new_dovahkiin->root = NULL;
        new_dovahkiin->source = NULL;
        new_dovahkiin->sink = NULL;
        new_dovahkiin->tempflux = 0;
    }
return (new_dovahkiin);
}
```

in the api.h is the definition of the structure DovahkiinSt:

```
 typedef struct _DovahkiinSt_t {
        vertex root;
        vertex source;
        vertex sink;
        u64 tempflux;
    }DovahkiinSt;
    typedef DovahkiinSt *DovahkiinP;
```

and in both api.c and main.c i have #include "api.h"
i dont get what is the problem with the sizeof(struct DovahkiinSt)

Comment: @Oswald has the right answer, but you can avoid this issue entirely by using the form `ptr = calloc(1, sizeof *ptr);`

Answer (score 4):

Use `sizeof(DovahkiinSt)` or `sizeof(struct _DovahkiinSt_t)`.

`sizeof(struct DovahkiinSt)` makes no sense, because `DovahkiinSt` is just a different name for `struct _DovahkiinSt_t`.